# Jquery datepicker display all days of month for a year

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jquery datepicker on a textbox to enter user birth date.For validation purposes I set max year to be "-16Y" of the current year, for min year I set year range to `yearRange: '1920:c'`. The problem is when I display it in the browser datepicker doesn't show all days of the max year (which is 1999). I think jquery set it to the maximum day of the current day (6th of August).So to work around this problem?

Here is my code for the datepicker:

```
$("#YearOFBirth").datepicker({

            maxDate: "-16Y",
            //showOn: "both",
           // buttonImage: "",
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '1920:c'
        }).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
                $(e.target).val("");
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

As you can see here in this image all days after 6th is disabled which isn't correct for year 1999

[image]

Note: I made a search for this but I found nothing. I don't even know how to ask this question properly

Comment: Buddy today is 6 aug 2015.exactly -16Y.Your code is correct.

Comment: @Bugfixer I know sir, but as you can see for year 1999 I can't choose any day after 6

Comment: Try july 1999.All days will be available.

Comment: But what if the user need to choose 23 of August 1999 as his birthdate

Comment: Well, then the user is younger than 16 years ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the maxDate yourself:

`var maxDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() - 16, 11, 31);`

And then give the `maxDate` to your datePicker. Like this you have all days available of the year which was 16 years before now. As the last day of the year is ALWAYS YYYY-12-31, it's not bad practice to hardcode it.

Comment: Thank you sir!! ... you are a lifesaver